# passing .env vars to node child process

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, child-process

I'm trying to pass some `env` variables to a child process started using [forever monitor](https://github.com/foreversd/forever-monitor), The problem is that I'm unable to load them from my custom .env file and pass to the child process.

This is my index.js script

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require('dotenv').config();
const forever = require('forever-monitor');
const path = require('path');
const script = path.format({dir: __dirname, base: 'pager.js'});

const child = new (forever.Monitor)(script, {
    max: 2,
    silent: false,
    env: {'EMAIL':  process.env.EMAIL, 'MPWD': process.env.MPWD}
});

//debug dotenv
console.log(process.env)

child.start();
```

How I can fix, maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you just add require('dotenv').config(); to pager.js?

Comment: I was using it inside  the `pager.js` script but the added env vars are not loaded